# How can I disable "Screenshot Saved" notification?

Tags: ps4

When I take a screenshot my PS4 shows "Screenshot saved" notification, and I think the same happens for videos too. But it hangs there for some time, and if I want to take another screenshot this notification stays there, like this:

[image: Screenshot saved notification]

How can I disable these notifications? I want my screenshots nice and clean!

Answer (score -1):

To remove the icon go to Settings > Notifications, scroll to the bottom and uncheck the box for 'When Taking Screenshots'.

Comment: this doesn't work for me! I unchecked this setting, but notifications are still shown

Comment: You can select which notifications you'd like to see by going to [Settings] > [Notifications] > [Pop-up Notifications]. Tick or untick the box next to type of notification to turn them on or off, or you can turn off notifications altogether.

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. i turned every notification off. i turned literally the whole concept of notifications off... still the screenshot ones plague me.